# extract numbers at specific position in a vector in r

Tags: r, regex

I have lots of vectors and every element has 3 numbers and I want to extract it to different columns.

```
test <- '1.0226 [1.0109; 1.0344]'
```

What I expected is

```
rr <- 1.0226
low_95 <- 1.0109
up_95 <- 1.0344
```

I thought I should use the `str_extract()` function to do this, but I don't know how to write the regex.

rr : extract number before `[`;

low_95 : extract number between `[` and `;`;

up_95 : extract number between `;` and `]`.

Comment: `str_extract_all(test, "[0-9.]+")` will give you all 3 numbers in order, in a list.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Regex for extracting number before `[` in R: `*\\[.*`

```
test <- '1.0226 [1.0109; 1.0344]'

rr <- gsub(" *\\[.*", "", test)
rr
# [1] "1.0226"
```

Regex for extracting number between `[` and `;` in R: `.*\\[|;.*`

```
test <- '1.0226 [1.0109; 1.0344]'

low_95 <- gsub(".*\\[|;.*", "", test)
low_95
# [1] "1.0109"
```

Regex for extracting number between `;` and `]` in R: `.*; |].*`

```
test <- '1.0226 [1.0109; 1.0344]'

up_95 <- gsub(".*; |].*", "", test)
up_95
# [1] "1.0344"
```

Answer (score 2):

we could use `strcapture` from base R:

```
prt <- data.frame(rr = numeric(),low_95 = numeric(), up_95 = numeric())

strcapture("(\\d+\\.?\\d+)\\D+\\[((?1));\\s*((?1))\\]",test,prt,perl = TRUE)


    rr low_95  up_95
1 1.0226 1.0109 1.0344
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are going to have other values in `test`, you can `extract` from `tidyr`.

```
data.frame(test) %>%
   tidyr::extract(test, paste0('num', 1:3), '(.*)\\[(.*);\\s*(.*)\\]')
```

Answer (score 1):

In case the numbers are every time at the same position you can use `read.table` after removing `[];` with `gsub`.

```
read.table(text=gsub("[][;]", "", test), col.names=c("rr","low_95","up_95"))
#      rr low_95  up_95
#1 1.0226 1.0109 1.0344
```

Answer (score 1):

With `data.table`:

```
test <- '1.0226 [1.0109; 1.0344]'
data.table::tstrsplit(test, " \\[|; |\\]")
[[1]]
[1] "1.0226"

[[2]]
[1] "1.0109"

[[3]]
[1] "1.0344"
```

Answer (score 0):

Using base R with `gregexpr` we can just extract out all numbers, then assign to separate variables:

```
test <- '1.0226 [1.0109; 1.0344]'
matches <- gregexpr('\\b\\d+(?:\\.\\d+)?\\b', test, perl=TRUE)
vec <- regmatches(test, matches)[[1]]
vec
rr <- vec[1]
low_94 <- vec[2]
up_95 <- vec[3]

[1] "1.0226" "1.0109" "1.0344"
```

Answer (score 0):

A fun way of doing this is via `sub`and multiple backreferencing:

```
strsplit(gsub("(^\\d+\\.\\d+)\\s\\[(\\d+\\.\\d+);\\s(\\d+\\.\\d+)]", "\\1,\\2,\\3", test), ",")
[[1]]
[1] "1.0226" "1.0109" "1.0344"
```

From there you can proceed by assigning the elements to your vectors of choice, for example:

```
rr <- unlist(strsplit(gsub("(^\\d+\\.\\d+)\\s\\[(\\d+\\.\\d+);\\s(\\d+\\.\\d+)]", "\\1,\\2,\\3", test), ","))[1]
[1] "1.0226"
```